# Контроллер не получает данные от websoket,a

Tags: javascript, java, spring, websocket

Пишу чат на вебсокетах. Использую sockjs.js и stomp.js. Соединение проходит успешно, сабскрайб на рассылку тоже. Но при попытке отправить на бекенд сообщение (для рассылки всем присоеденившимся к чату) на нужный контролллер ничего не приходит, хотя в консоль либа пишет что данные отправила:

```
>>> SEND
destination:/app/app-dest-prefix/chat
content-length:76

{"from":"Lesha","text":"message","timeCreation":"2017-10-12T15:26:29.410Z"}
```

так я присоединяюсь

```
stompClient = Stomp.over(new SockJS("/ContactBook/app/cbxSoc"));
```

так сабскрайблюсь:

```
stompClient.subscribe('/topic/messages', function (message) {
                console.log(message);
            });
```

так я отправляю сообщение:

```
stompClient.send("/app-dest-prefix/chat", {}, JSON.stringify({'from':'Lesha', 'text':$scope.chatInput, 'timeCreation':new Date()})
```

такой у меня контроллер

```
@Controller
public class ChatController {

@MessageMapping("/chat")
@SendTo("/topic/messages")
public Message send(Message message){
    String time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(new Date());
    message.setTimeCreation(time);
    return message;
}
```

}

такая конфигурация:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class CbxSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer{

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry ser) {
    ser.addEndpoint("/cbxSoc").withSockJS();
}

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    // Prefix for messages FROM client TO server
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app-dest-prefix");
    // Prefix for messages FROM server TO client
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/events", "/topic", "/queue");
    config.setUserDestinationPrefix("/user");

}

}
```

Подскажите, кто в курсе, где я ошибся. Спасибо. Такое ощущение, что урл не верный указал, но судя по документации всё правильно...

**UPD**
Может кто-то знает как отхендлить вообще всё. что приходит от клиента (не только по определённому пути, который указана в @MessageMapping("/chat"))?

**UPD2**
Добавил хендлер для отлавливания вообще всех сообщению вебсокета

```
 @Override
public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) 
{
    registration.setInterceptors(new MyChannelInterceptor());
}

public class MyChannelInterceptor extends ChannelInterceptorAdapter {

@Override
public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
    StompHeaderAccessor accessor = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(message);
    //StompCommand command = accessor.getStompCommand();
    return message;
}
}
```

При отправке клиентом сообщения этот хендлер его отлавливает, но на контроллер всё равно не доходит..[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD3** пример лог мапинга

```
2017-10-22 20:30:19  INFO RequestMappingHandlerMapping:220 - Mapped "{[/client/managers],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public java.util.List com.miroktell.contactbook.controllers.ClientController.getManagers()
2017-10-22 20:30:19  INFO RequestMappingHandlerMapping:220 - Mapped "{[/client/filter],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public com.miroktell.contactbook.containers.RowsContainer com.miroktell.contactbook.controllers.ClientController.getClientsByFilter(com.miroktell.contactbook.containers.ClientListFilter) throws java.io.IOException
2017-10-22 20:30:19  INFO RequestMappingHandlerMapping:220 - Mapped "{[/client/getFullClientByPhoneNumber],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public com.miroktell.contactbook.model.Client com.miroktell.contactbook.controllers.ClientController.getFullClientByPhoneNumber(java.lang.String)
2017-10-22 20:30:19  INFO RequestMappingHandlerMapping:220 - Mapped "{[/client/addNotice],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public com.miroktell.contactbook.utils.MyMesage com.miroktell.contactbook.controllers.ClientController.addNotice(com.miroktell.contactbook.model.ClientNotice)
2017-10-22 20:30:19  INFO RequestMappingHandlerMapping:220 - Mapped "{[/util/filter/delete/{id}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public com.miroktell.contactbook.utils.MyMesage com.miroktell.contactbook.controllers.UtilController.deleteFilter(int)
2017-10-22 20:30:19  INFO SimpleUrlHandlerMapping:315 - Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler]
2017-10-22 20:30:19  INFO RequestMappingHandlerAdapter:523 - Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Sun Oct 22 20:30:18 EEST 2017]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
```

Answer (score 3):

1) Вы отсылаете JSON строку, соответственно вы должны прописать в конструкторе соответствующие аннотация для разбора данных

2) Не работал с этой веткой АПИ, но мне кажется Вам стоит поиграться с конфигурацией, а именно `enableSimpleBroker("/events", "/topic", "/queue")` .У Вас неявно указана ссылка, по которой контроллер должен считывать данные. В Вашем же случаи это должно быть `@MessageMapping("/app-dest-prefix/chat")`. Пробуйте

Comment: По поводу первого пункта: Вы про приведение json к java объекту? Если да. то на сколько я понимаю, этим у меня занимается jackson. По поводу второго, где у меня не явно указана ссылка на контроллер, который считывает данные? Попробовал поменять строчку контроллера на вашу @MessageMapping("/app-dest-prefix/chat"). Ситуация не изменилась

Comment: У Вас в контроллере принимаемый объект не помечен соответствующей аннотацией '@ResponseBody public Message send(@RequestBody Message message)'. Покажите лог маппинга активных ссылок на контроллеры. Попробуйте еще использовать за место '@MessageMapping("/chat")' использовать '@RequestMapping(value = "/chat", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = {"Content-type=application/json"})

Comment: добавил пример мапинг лога. По поводу аннотации, '@RequestMapping она же используется для http запросов, а у меня веб сокет

Answer (score 0):

Проблема осталась не решенной. Вышел из ситуации (пока не разберусь) таким образом. Сообщение на бэкенд отправляю через обычный http, а уже рассылку всем сабскрайберам осуществляю через вебсокет.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/testChat", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers="Accept=application/json")
public void testChat(@RequestBody Message message){
    Logger.getLogger(NotificationController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "RECEIVED MESSAGE FROM CLIENT: \n"+message);
    this.simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/messages", message);
    Logger.getLogger(NotificationController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "SENDED THIS MESSAGE TO ALL SUBSCRIBERS: /topic/messages");
}
```

Понимаю что так делать - полный бред, но пока проблема не решена, это вроде как единственный рабочий способ...Спасибо @GenCloud за попытку помочь.

Answer (score 0):

При создании соединения на клиенте нужно указывать этот адресс `ser.addEndpoint("/cbxSoc").withSockJS();`